# Marquee content not showing

Tags: css, flexbox, marquee

I have Designed a marquee wrapper with css keyframes. But the marquee content is not showing.

I have designed this from https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/BygPMY

But don't know why the marquee content is not showing up..
The animation and all that stuff is working absolutely fine.
Sir, please help me identify the problem.

```css
.landing-ratecard-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .ratecard-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner span {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner span .rate {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  color: #fff;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




<div class="landing-ratecard-wrapper d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h5 class="ratecard-title">Rate Card</h5>
                        <div class="marquee">
                            <div class="marquee--inner">
                                <span>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing height for

```
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee {
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      position: relative;
      height: 150px;
    }
```

Also set top to 0 in class `landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner`

```css
.landing-ratecard-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .ratecard-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner span {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner span .rate {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  color: #fff;
}
.landing-ratecard-wrapper .marquee .marquee--inner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




<div class="landing-ratecard-wrapper d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h5 class="ratecard-title">Rate Card</h5>
                        <div class="marquee">
                            <div class="marquee--inner">
                                <span>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                    <div class="rate">lorem ipsum</div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome. :) If this answers your question kindly mark it as answer.